# Linhas específicas de uma tabela

Tags: sql

Olá!!
Eu tenho a tabela OPERACAO onde possuo 3 colunas: Codoper, descricao, nautureza. Eu tenho que projetar a descrição e a natureza de todas as operações de entrada. Depois ordenar pelo código da operação. O código de operação 1, 3 e 6 são as minhas operações de entrada. O código 2, 4 e 5 são de saída. Estou travado no where...

```
Select operacao.descricao, operacao.natureza, operacao.codoper
From operacao
Where ___________________
Order by operacao.codoper
```

Se alguém puder de dar uma dica ou ajuda fico agradecido.

Comment: where codoper in (1,3,6)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Deu certo!!

Comment: Parece que falta uma coluna que indique o tipo de operação...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

Acredito que isso te atenda.

`WHERE operacao.codoper IN (1, 3, 6)`